# Python Kivy, rsa. При передачи из textinput строки для шифрования, функция выдает ошибку

Tags: python-3.x, rsa, kivy

```
(pubkey, privkey) = rsa.newkeys(1024)

def crypt(self,message,pubk=pubkey):
    mb= str.encode(message)
    cryptmessage = rsa.encrypt(mb, pubk)
    return cryptmessage
```

### Собственно, это функция шифрования вводимой строки.

```
<ScreenCrypt>:

BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    width:400
    height: 400

    TextInput:
        id:edit_message_for_crypt
        size_hint_y:None
        height:dp(100)
        hint_text:"Введите сообщение для шифрования"

    Button:
        height: dp(100)
        size_hint_y:None
        background_color: 1, .3, .4, .85
        text:"Зашифровать "
        on_press:
            output_crypt_message.text = app.crypt(root.ids.edit_message_for_crypt.text,)


    TextInput:
        id:output_crypt_message
        size_hint_y: None
        height:dp(100)
        text:
```

### Kv файл действующего скрина.

Сама ошибка

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 3: invalid start byte

В чем суть ошибки и как ее исправить?

Comment: Попробуйте в kv написать все латиницей.

Comment: А ещё boxlayout... Я так понял должен находиться в screencrypt, тогда нужно сделать отступ. А ещё вот это: output_crypt_message.text = app.crypt(root.ids.edit_message_for_crypt.text,) в конце запятая, которая ни к чему.  
output_crypt_message - присвойте значению text:"".